# WCF using Spring.NET woes

Tags: wcf, spring.net

I've torn out all but two hairs on my head trying to get my WCF services hosted in IIS 7.5.
I'm using Spring.NET to create my service instances, but I'm having no luck getting it up and running.

I encounter the following exception:

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].
```

My WCF configuration is as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureBinding" allowCookies="false">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None">
          <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="TestService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://ws.local.com/TestService.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint name="secureEndpoint" contract="Services.Interfaces.ITestService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureBinding" address="https://ws.local.com/TestService.svc" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

What am I missing here?